# Couchdb conceptual problems

Tags: caching, couchdb, updating

As I understand, to update any object with couchdb. I have to send the whole object back since it is actually "inserting" a new revision for the same id. This is all neat and works quite well.

But then I have a problem, I'm not so sure how should I handle that. I have an object that can't be sent to my user completely. I have to hide certain informations such as password hash.

The data is sent to the client, the revision is sent too. Now when I try to update my object I have one problem. Since some data is missing, the update will erase the attributes that are missing from my user.

That said, the easiest way I have is to get the object from couchdb, check if id and rev matches. If it does match, merge the object with the missing attributes. It will work pretty well and I can support deleting attributes too.

Then using this technique, I could add my objects to a cache that will reduce the time to query frequent objects from the database. If the object can be updated, then clear the cache for that id. If the object is newer, then I'll have to handle the error or merge the object.

Is there any better "good way" to handle this problem?

**edit**

After thinking about it during the night, I think I found a much much better solution. Instead of having my username and password inside my profile. I'll separate the identification object from the use profile.

In other words, I'll have to split up the object as much as possible to keep things isolated... On the plus side, I can add multiple authentication for one profile without messing with the profile itself. I can return profiles and anything necessary without returning any secret object.

It will complicate a bit the logic of insertion but it should be quite easy...

1. Get 1 id from couchdb using the uuid api "_uuids"
2. Insert password authentications (username, password, profile_id) using that uuid
3. If succeed, insert profile using the uuid that we got at 1

If anything wrong happen, rollback and tell the users what's wrong.

Also the nice thing about this method is that I can add access_token for oauth2 using the profile id and the logic will be almost the same as password, the auth type will differ but any auth type should work almost the same.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, extracting the secret stuff from the profile documents sounds like the way to go.

Comment: I got it to work and read that there is an API to get uuids: `server/_uuids` This way I can insert my auth with a valid id before I even insert the profile. I did work with mongodb and it was like old days. Doing something with couchdb is forcing me to rethink how to structure data.